# Is it possible to convert BroadcastReceiver to Coroutines?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, kotlin-coroutines

I recently learned `Coroutines` and I am trying my best to implement it to everything.

I learned you could convert a callback to a `coroutine`.

Is it possible to convert a `Broadcast Receiver` to `coroutines` by using `suspendCoroutine`?

How do I do this?

Comment: The problem is that it's fully different things. Maybe your question is about how to make something in background  in broadcast receiver?

Comment: I see two options: 
1) Use `GlobalScope.launch{}`. This way `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive` will return immediately and die, but `GlobalScope` will live on until app process dies (when?)
2) Start `IntentService` and start blocking Coroutine in IntentService, because `IntentService` runs on background thread

Comment: I'm fairly new to coroutines as well, but would it work to use runBlocking inside the onReceive function?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way (courtesy of [leonardkraemer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265739/leonardkraemer) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53520496/775282)):

```
suspend fun Context.getCurrentScanResults(): List<ScanResult> {
    val wifiManager = getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as? WifiManager ?: return listOf()
    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
        val wifiScanReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(c: Context, intent: Intent) {
                if (intent.action == WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION) {
                    unregisterReceiver(this)
                    continuation.resume(wifiManager.scanResults)
                }
            }
        }
        continuation.invokeOnCancellation {
            unregisterReceiver(wifiScanReceiver)
        }
        registerReceiver(wifiScanReceiver, IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION))
        wifiManager.startScan()
    }
}
```